# weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container$Listener

Tags: web-services, cxf, weblogic12c

I have an JAVA web application running in Apache Tomcat server 7.0.88. the application has a single webpage called index.jsp having a textbox and an submit button. on clicking this submit button, a cxf web service is called that fetches the data against the value that would have been entered in the textbox.
now, when i am creating a war outta it in order to deploy this application into Oracle weblogic server 12c, below exception is coming.this exception is appearing when i click "activate changes" in weblogic console after browsing the war file.

Exception Trace:

<04-Jul-2018, 12:20:50,200 PM BST>    
<04-Jul-2018, 12:20:50,662 PM BST>

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: @lmiguelmh  no mate :( 
any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of your dependencies, I made it work with these dependencies:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <cxf.version>3.1.4</cxf.version>
    <cxf.xjc-utils.version>3.0.5</cxf.xjc-utils.version>
    ...
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.xjc-utils.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

I took this from: [Why and How to use Apache CXF Service in WebLogic 12c?](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=8308) and the [pom.xml from the same post: Apache CXF Service in Weblogic 12c](https://github.com/jaysensharma/MiddlewareMagicDemos/blob/master/WebLogic/WebService/WebLogic12c_CXF_Demo_Maven/pom.xml)